# Wordpress: Check if there are previous posts before displaying link

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I'm using the following code to display a 'previous posts' link on my Wordpress blog.

```
     <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></li>
</ul
</nav>
```

Problem is, when there ARN'T any previous posts, while the link doesn't display, I still get

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li><</li>
</ul
</nav>
```

Printed out. Is there an if() statement I could wrap around it all so it checks if there are any previous posts, and only prints it out if there are?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<?php
    if($link = get_previous_posts_link()) {
        echo '<ul><li>'.$link.'</li></ul>';
?>
```

`get_previous_posts_link` returns null (falsy value) if there isn't any previous post.

Comment: Should't it be `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: No @brasofilo; it is a little confusing, I know. The if written like that first assigns the result of `get_previous_posts_link()` to `$link`, then checks the assignment value (the return value of an assignment is the value being assigned), and, as I said below the code, the function returns null if there isn't any previous post, so the code is not called in that case.

Comment: needed to change get_previous_posts_link() to get_previous_post_link() (singular "post")

Answer (score 10):

Just to be clear:

Colin's answer isn't correct in my opinion.
get_previous_post is not deprecated, previous_post is.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post

For me the use of get_next_post works still fine for me.

```
if(get_next_post()) {  }
if(get_previous_post()) {  }
```

Comment: Works for me in WP WordPress 4.6.1

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers worked for me.
I solved it this way:

```
$next = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)); //next post url
$prev= get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)); //previous post url
<?php if (get_the_permalink()!=$prev): ?>
    <a href='<?php echo $prev ?>'>Previous</a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (get_the_permalink()!=$next): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $next ?>">Next</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

for people checking this in 2013, get_previous_post has been depreciated.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post

I used to use this :/

```
if(get_next_post()) { echo 'next'; }
if(get_previous_post()) { echo 'last'; }
```

But now I use this :)

```
if(get_next_posts_link()) { echo 'next'; }
if(get_previous_posts_link()) { echo 'last'; }
```