# Show previous/next only when there is a previous/next page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to get a pagination on the `index.php` working. What I come up with yet looks something like this:

```
<nav>
  <a href="<?php previous_posts(); ?>" class="btn prev-page">Previous Page</a>
  <a href="<?php next_posts(); ?>" class="btn next-page">Next Page</a>
</nav>
```

However, I'd like to show the Previous/Next buttons only, when there actually exists a previous/next page. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: some more code? how can you understand if there is a previous or next post?

Comment: this has been solved before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723433/wordpress-check-if-there-are-previous-posts-before-displaying-link

Answer (score 0):

Put this where you want to display previous/next page

```
<?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
```

and in functions.php add

```
function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {
     if( is_singular() )
        return;
     global $wp_query;
     /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;
     $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );
     /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;
     /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }
    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }
    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";
    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>') );
    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );
        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }
     /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }
     /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }
     /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
       printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>') );
    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
 }
```

*Source: [WPBegginer](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/)*